# Реализация оплаты в телеграмм боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, платежи

Необходимо реализовать оплату в телеграмм боте, что для этого необходимо и какая платёжная система или сервис приёма платежей подойдёт без открытия ООО/ИП.

Comment: Я не осведомлён в этой теме, поэтому, если кто-то может просветить, будьте добры или подкиньте материалы для чтения

Comment: необходимо почитать статью 171 УК РФ.        Осуществление предпринимательской деятельности без регистрации или без лицензии либо без аккредитации в национальной системе аккредитации            наказывается штрафом в размере до трехсот тысяч рублей или в размере заработной платы или иного дохода осужденного за период до двух лет, либо обязательными работами на срок до четырехсот восьмидесяти часов, либо арестом на срок до шести месяцев.

Comment: @Интик Вообще-то существует такое понятие как "[самозанятый](https://npd.nalog.ru/)".

Comment: но регистрироваться в фнс всёравно нужно.и перед изучением платёжных систем лучше почитать законы, ато патом сюрприз будет.

Comment: Телеграм-бот Donate позволяет принимать оплату во многих валютах, в том числе и в крипте

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Telegram имеется [встроенный метод платежей](https://telegram.org/blog/payments-2-0-scheduled-voice-chats/ru?ln=a).

> Платёжные боты существуют в Telegram с 2017 года. С их помощью можно
> безопасно оплачивать товары и услуги вроде доставки пиццы, не покидая
> приложения.
>
> Для оплаты можно использовать любое приложение – в том числе Telegram
> для компьютеров. Покупатель также может оставить чаевые, чтобы
> поддержать любимого автора, кафе или магазин.
>
> Платформа для платежей открытая и бесплатная – Telegram не берёт
> комиссии и не хранит платежную информацию. Реквизиты отправляются
> напрямую платежной системе, а адрес для доставки — продавцу, чтобы он
> мог отправить товар.

Испытать возможности на бесплатных тестовых товарах и услугах можно в этом [канале](https://t.me/TestStore/2).

На данный момент Telegram поддерживает платежи из более чем 200 стран через следующие платежные системы:

- Stripe
- YooMoney ([ЮSelf](https://promo.yoomoney.ru/promo-self-employed) - бесплатный сервис для самозанятых)
- [Sberbank](http://www.sberbank.ru/ru/legal/bankingservice/internet_acquiring)
- Tranzzo
- Payme
- CLICK
- LiqPay
- ECOMMPAY
- PayMaster

Для подключения оплаты:

1. у [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather) выберите своего бота
2. Перейдите в раздел Payments
3. Выберите платёжного провайдера
4. Для разработки и отладки выберите Connect *** TEST
5. Для "боевой" среды выберите Connetct *** LIVE

- [Описание пошагового процесса оплаты](https://core.telegram.org/bots/payments#step-by-step-process)
- [Описание API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputinvoicemessagecontent)
- [Пример реализации с помощью pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/payments_example.py)
- [Пример реализации с помощью Telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/master/telethon_examples/payment.py)